ISR not returning properly
I get the error "check_cs(0x0020): not a valid code segment !" from Bochs after going through the isr for the timer: 0x20.
Here's the code for the isr:
void timer_isr() {
    // Acknowledge the PIC (send EOI)
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, 0x20);  // Acknowledge interrupt to PIC 2

    // Send EOI to PIC 1 (master)
    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, 0x20);  // Acknowledge interrupt to PIC 1

    println("You're in the timer isr.");

    asm __volatile__ ("iret");
}

I'm following the interrupts tutorial from osdev.org, this is their code sample for filling the IDT. I've added setting the timer isr to IRQ 0.
void init_idt() {
    idtr.base = (uintptr_t)&idt[0];
    idtr.limit = (u16)sizeof(idtEntry) * IDT_MAX_DESCRIPTORS - 1;

    for (u8 vector = 0; vector < 32; vector++) {
        idt_set_descriptor(vector, isr_stub_table[vector], 0x8E);
        vectors[vector] = true;
    }

    // Set the PIC Timer interrupt
    idt_set_descriptor(0x20, timer_isr, 0x8E);
    vectors[0x20] = true;

    asm __volatile__ ("lidt %0" : : "m"(idtr)); // load the new IDT
    asm __volatile__ ("sti"); // set the interrupt flag
}

I'm remapping the PIC and setting up the GDT before any of this is called. The GDT and IDT are filled out fine according to Bochs. Here's the github repo for the project: https://github.com/Wardence1/Basic_OS
Thanks in advance for the help!

Your ISR isn't declared with __attribute__((interrupt)), you just randomly run iret with the stack pointer pointing wherever GCC had it.  Which is definitely not at the exception-return frame, because the function body includes a function call (to println) so GCC would have done some pushes and/or sub esp, imm to get ESP 16-byte aligned before the call.  Asm-level debugging will shows you what's going on if execution does reach the interrupt handler.  __attribute__((interrupt)) will make it save/restore all registers which your function also wasn't doing.

Related: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-interrupt-function-attribute_002c-x86 /  https://www.reddit.com/r/osdev/comments/txrbnq/gccs_attribute_interrupt/

Funny before you even asked this, a couple of hours ago I made a pull request to fix all this up. I happened to look at some repos and noticed your comments in the commits that suggested problems so I spent a few minutes committing some changes. You can find my pull request here: https://github.com/Wardence1/Basic_OS/pulls . You can see the differences here: https://github.com/Wardence1/Basic_OS/pull/2/files

@MichealPetch Haha! Thank you both, It's working now. I followed the instructions from the GCC docs. Happy Holidays to you both!

@JacksonKidwell : Happy Holiday to you too. I don't really recommend the interrupt attribute method as you lose control of the ability to access the state of the registers at the time of the interrupt occurred; makes generating debug traces from the kernel harder; can't handle system call argument passing; and doesn't handle switching the segment registers to kernel ones if coming from user mode. The pull request I made used your existing stub handlers (which can be enhanced later on) to handle external interrupts as well as exceptions.
